# Rails ActiveModel Serializer and merge method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, serialization

I have an Active Model Serializer defined for my model and everything works fine when I call render json passing a single collection, like this:

```
render json: @collection
```

The problem is when I try to merge different attributes and collections, for example:

```
json_response = service.errors.merge(attribute1: value1)
render json: json_response.merge(collection1: @collection, collection2: @collection2)
```

When I do that, the collections does not use the defined Active Record Serializer. Instead, they just serialize all their attributes.

How can I ensure that when I do these merges, the serialization still uses the Active Record Serializer that I have defined for them?

Comment: What is `service` is it a database entry?

Comment: No, it's a class that executes some calculations and is used as a variable inside the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize them directly before the render:

```
json_response = service.errors.merge(attribute1: value1)
render json: json_response.merge(
  collection1: ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(@collection).as_json, 
  collection2: ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(@collection2).as_json
)
```